# What are some good textbooks on material and crystal physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, material-science, crystals, ferromagnetism, piezoelectric

I am looking for good physics textbooks on materials and crystal physics, I do not mind if they are a bit general but they must cover useful topics. However, the specific topics I would like some suggestions for are piezo-electricity, ferroelectricity and ferromagnetism in crystals and materials.

I would like them to be as rigorous as possible as I need more theoretical frameworks that these phenomena occur in rather than a focus on engineering/application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual one should start with the fundamental Solid State books for which I recommend

1. Introduction to Solid State Physics - Kittel
2. Solid State Physics - Ashcroft & Mermin
3. [Solid-State Physics: An Introduction to Principles of Materials Science -
   Ibach & Lüth](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-05342-3)

For the books concerning with the magnetism I can list you some names, none of which I can say much because I did not read them thoroughly myself

1. [Fundamentals of Magnetism - Getzlaff](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-31152-2)
2. [Magnetism, Basics and Applications - Stefanita](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-22977-0)
3. [Magnetism, From Fundamentals to Nanoscale Dynamics - Stohr & Siegmann](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-30283-4)
4. [Modern Theory of Magnetism in Metals and Alloys - Kakehashi](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-33401-6)
5. [Quantum Theory of Magnetism - Nolting & Ramakanth](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-85416-6)

I also made a fast search for the books on Piezoelectricity in Springerlink and here is the list. For these books I cannot say anything at all since I did not even open their cover.

1. [Piezoelectricity Evolution and Future of a Technology - HeywangKarl & Lubitz & Wersing](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-68683-5)
2. [Special Topics in the Theory of Piezoelectricity - Yang](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-89498-0)
3. [An Introduction to the Theory of Piezoelectricity - Yang](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b101799)
4. [Advanced Mechanics of Piezoelectricity - Qin](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-29767-0)

Comment: I would add Condensed Matter Physics by Marder https://books.google.fr/books/about/Condensed_Matter_Physics.html?id=ijloadAt4BQC&redir_esc=y

Comment: If one is studying crystals or intersecting anisotropy in any way, Nye's *Physical Properties of Crystals: Their Representation by Tensors and Matrices* is an excellent reference.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Does that book at all cover Piezo-electricity? I'm beginning to think that it is not a subject that is covered exclusively by a book, but somewhat glossed over in books written on other areas.

Comment: @GramCracker I have edited my answer, it may help

Comment: @GramCracker There’s a chapter thoroughly covering the structure and unique aspects of the piezoelectricity tensor (but not the mechanism; Nye is about understanding the tensors, math, and crystal symmetry).

Comment: Brilliant, I'll give it a look.